# Get Count(*) of instance where it is grouped by date.

Tags: sql, mariadb

A SQL query where a count will be returned by date_created

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records_call
WHERE source_address = '1234' 
AND date_created >= '2015-02-24 12:00:00'
```

How would I get the count ordered by date?

Comment: could you please provide the table schema?

Comment: What specific database are you using?

Comment: you may use this site to create a sample http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ so we may better help you

Comment: You asked: "How would I get the count ordered by date?" .. do you mean "How would I get the count ordered by **day**?" (since "date" includes time component)

Comment: Sorry guys. MariaDB . Im using SequelPro ( mysql ) . The one below works, however id does it by time as well. Is there a way I can group it without the time ?

Comment: need to group by TRUNC(date_created) ... any of the below solutions would do that .. add the TRUNC ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the results as count(*) per date in two columns you need to include the date in the select and use it in a group by clause:

```
SELECT DATE(date_created) AS "Date Created", COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM records_call
WHERE source_address = '1234' 
  AND date_created >= '2015-02-24 12:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(date_created)
ORDER BY DATE(date_created)
```

As the `date_created` includes a time component you might want to cast it to just a date unless all dates have the exact same time - how you do this depends on what database you are using, it could be `cast(date_created as date)`, `DATE(date_created)` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This should work on most databases:

```
SELECT date_created, COUNT(*) FROM records_call
WHERE source_address = '1234' 
AND date_created >= '2015-02-24 12:00:00'
GROUP BY date_created
ORDER BY date_created
```